# C / Copy String with dynamic malloc, from const char * org to char ** cpy

Tags: c, pointers, new-operator

I want to copy a const string `const char * org` to `char **cpy`, but my code doesn't work.

I was thinking getting the lenght of my original string and and using `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory, in order to just copy `*org` to `**cpy` would work, but it doesn't.

Where is my mistake? Cant't I use `strcpy` for a pointer to a pointer or how exactly do I do it?

I'm very new to this, so I appologize in advance if I don't see something really simple.

```
int string_dd_copy(char **cpy, const char * org)

    {
      int i = 0;
      while(org[i] != '\0'){
        ++i;
      }
      if(i == 0){
        return 0;
      }
      *cpy = malloc(i* sizeof(char));
      strcpy(*cpy, org);
      printf("%s", *cpy);

      return 1;
    }
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
int string_dd_copy();
char **a;
char *b = "Iam";
string_dd_copy(a, b);
return 0;
}

int string_dd_copy(char **cpy, const char * org)
{
  cpy = malloc(1 + strlen(org));
  strcpy(*cpy, org);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to allocate for the terminating null-character.

Comment: By the way, why don't you use `strlen()`?

Comment: And instead of using `char **cpy`,return a `char *` and  just do `char *cpy = malloc( 1 + strlen( org ) ); strcpy( cpy, org ); return( cpy );`.  Or just use [`strdup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) if you're on a POSIX system.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And returning `0` can be replaced by returning `NULL`.

Comment: @MikeCAT I was keeping the comment short.  Full duplication of the originally-posted functionality is left as an exercise. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int string_dd_copy( char **cpy, const char *org )
{
    if( strlen(org)  == 0 ){
        printf( "no data\n");
        return 0;
    }

    *cpy = malloc( strlen( org ) + 1 );

    strcpy( *cpy, org );

    printf("%s\n", *cpy);

      return 1;
}
int main()
{

    const char *teststring = "hello world";
    const char *noData = "";

    char *testptr;
    string_dd_copy( &testptr, teststring );
    free( testptr );

    string_dd_copy( &testptr, noData );
    return 0;
}
```